# Viber Node.JS Bot API - RichMediaMessage object - doesn't work

Tags: node.js, chatbot, viber, viber-api, viber-bot

Without min api version -

```
const message = new RichMediaMessage(SAMPLE_RICH_MEDIA);
```

With min api version -

```
const message = new RichMediaMessage(SAMPLE_RICH_MEDIA, null, [], undefined, undefined, null, 7);
```

Both doesn't work while sending

```
response.send(message);
```

The error log is like below
[image]

Normal text message works well

```
const message = new TextMessage('hi');

response.send(message);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue.
In their api documentation,
https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/nodejs-bot-api/#RichMediaMessage

```
"ButtonsGroupRows": 2 (this should be => 4+1=5)
```

Changing "2" to "5" solved it.